# How to fix "uninitialized constant List::Task (NameError)" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Output: <'class:List'> uninitialized constant List::Task (NameError)
You have created a new list

---

What I think is happening is that when I call Task.new, the List class is looking for possibly a task method or variable within its own class.

So far I tried using `include Task` and `require Task` in my List class with no luck. I also tried to declare the List class in my Task class. I also tried making the list class a parent of the Task class. After some digging online I thought it was the Ruby version and even changed the PATH to an older ruby version.

```
class List
    attr_reader :all_tasks
    if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME

        my_list = List.new
        puts 'You have created a new list'
        my_list.add(Task.new('Make breakfest'))
        puts 'You added a task'
    end
    def initialize
      @all_tasks = []
    end

    def add(task)
        all_tasks << task
    end
end

class Task
  attr_reader :description
  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end
end
```

Comment: Look carefully at your code: at which point in your code do you attempt to instantiate `Task`? At which point do you define `Task`? Which of those two points comes before the other? What does that tell you about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have helped if you provided more information about where (like: in which files) the classes are defined and how you call/execute your ruby code.

Usually, you would put code in a `lib` directory, with one class per file and strong semantics (`class List` goes into `lib/list.rb`), but its a tiny bit more complicated than that.

If you want to hack around and learn play a bit with ruby it is also perfectly understandable, that you do not want to cope with `require`ing (loading) other files, dealing with dependencies and all that (although this will need to happen one day as with most other programming languages).

For now, this would fix your issue and should get you going:

```
# file name: task_list_program.rb (or anything you want)
class Task
  attr_reader :description
  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end
end

class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks
  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
      all_tasks << task
  end
end

# note that for playing around in a single file, you actually
# do not even need the 'if ...' part here
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  my_list = List.new
  puts 'You have created a new list'
  my_list.add(Task.new('Make breakfest'))
  puts 'You added a task'
end
```

The main "trick" here is to move the `if __FILE__ == ...` thing out of your class definition, because otherwise (you are accidentally dealing with a special case here), stuff evaluated in that class at runtime will not be able to pick up and reference other "definitions" in the way you seem to expect.

I hope this helps you to get going. The differences between the code example could teach you a lot, e.g. about "namespaces" (which afaik are not a real concept in Ruby), but I believe this short answer is good enough to get you started and **have some fun with ruby** (and welcome at SO by the way)!

("execute" the file like this: `ruby task_list_program.rb`).

Answer (score 0):

```
class List
  class Task
    attr_reader :description
    def initialize(description)
      @description = description
    end
  end

  attr_reader :all_tasks
  if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME

    my_list = List.new
    puts 'You have created a new list'
    List::Task.new('Make breakfest')
    # my_list.add(Task.new('Make breakfest'))
    puts 'You added a task'
  end

  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
    all_tasks << task
  end

end
```

1. The first issue what we had in this file, that we try to call `Task` class before implemented!
2. You don't correct call `Task` class `my_list.add(Task.new('Make breakfest'))` 
   correct is List::Task.new('Make breakfast')

Comment: how did you test? Show please your error! 
P.S If you testing though rails console, you need restart console after update Class!!

Comment: I've used both visual studio code and sublime text to run this. After trying your solution I got the same exact error even when I pasted your solution to a new file and tested it there.

Comment: The same thing happened when I tried running both files through command prompt as well through "ruby todo.rb" I tried using both ruby version 2.2 and 2.6

Comment: Dear @ri_ji there not a good practice put negative rating to the person who wants to help you, but I hope my code helped you!

I updated code please check and let me know if now code is work!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to posting to this site and am sorry for the rude vote. I appreciate your patience and effort to help me.

Comment: @AndriyKondzolko I really appreciate your effort Andriy (also being very responsive to the original reporter, nice - even if it was downvoted!), but a code-only answer without comments is not always helpful as an Stack-Overflow answer. Maybe you could incorporate some text (just a few sentences, like your comment about the rails console or how you executed the code you posted).